# $L^2$-Sobolev space

Tags: functional-analysis, sobolev-spaces

I am looking at the proof of the following lemma and I don't understand the conclusion.

Lemma: For $k\geq 0$ integer, let $f=\sum_{n\in \mathbb{Z^d}}{c_n\chi_n}\in L^2(\mathbb{T}^d)$. Then 
$$f\in H^k(\mathbb{T}^d)\iff \sum_{n\in \mathbb{Z}^d}{\mid c_n\mid^2\parallel n\parallel_2^{2k}}<\infty.$$

Proof of "$\Leftarrow$": For any $\alpha :\parallel\alpha\parallel_1\leq k$ we have $n_1^{\alpha_1}\cdots n_d^{\alpha_d}=n^\alpha\leq\parallel n\parallel_2^{k}$. So the sum 
$$\sum_{\mid\alpha\mid\leq k}{\sum_{n\in \mathbb{Z}^d}{\mid(2\pi in)^\alpha c_n\mid^2}}<\infty.$$

From this it should follow that the partial sums $\sum_{\parallel n\parallel_2<N}{c_n\chi_n}$ of the Fourier series of $f$ converges even in the $H^k$ norm induced from $L^2(\mathbb{T})^{K(k)}$.

I think I need more details. I don't get why the convergence of the series above should imply the convergence of the Fourier partial sums w.r.to the $H^k$ norm. Thanks for any help.

Comment: The condition ensures that the Fourier series of $D^\alpha f$ converges in the $L^2$-norm for all $\alpha$ with $\lVert\alpha\rVert_1 \leqslant k$.

Comment: ok I think I am also a bit lost with the notation. So if I am right then $\parallel D^\alpha f\parallel_2^2=\sum_{n\in \mathbb{Z}^d}{\mid(2\pi i n)^\alpha c_n\mid^2}$, and $\sum_{\mid\alpha\mid\leq k}{\parallel D^\alpha f\parallel_2^2}=\parallel f\parallel_{H^k}^2<\infty$ but what is now with the partial sums? why am I summing over $\parallel n\parallel _2\leq N$?

Comment: What is $L^2$-Sobolev space ? Do you mean $W^1_2$ or $W^2_2$ or what ?

Comment: I learned it as the closure of $C^\infty(\mathbb{T}^d)$ in $(L^2(\mathbb{T^d})^{K(k)}$